# How to render dynamic HTML in Angular

Tags: angular, angular7

How to render dynamic html inside `{{ name }}`?

```js
let fname="faisal";
data1="<h1>{{fname}}</h1>";

let lname="Khan";
data2="<h1>{{lname}}</h1>";
```

how to get output like this : `{{ data1 }} {{ data2 }}` = `faisal khan`

Comment: Why don't you put the `h1` into the template, then do `<h1>{{ fname }} {{ lname }}</h1>`? That way you'll only have a single element, too.

Comment: https://angular.io/start

Answer (score 0):

You can display your full name without data1, data2

If you have `data1`, `data2` you need style for h1 `display: inline-block`

```
<h1>{{fname}} {{lname}}</h1>
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcw58e